# what should i do to convert 1000 as 1 0 0 0 where 1000 is int? in (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, integer, mapping

adding spaces between a given integer.
eg:999 should be printed as 9 9 9.
eg2:1234 should be printed as 1 2 3 4

can you please provide an easy solution. If possible with different methods

tried but did not get any result.

thank you

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: What did you try? Remember, you can [edit] your question at any time. *Hint*: You should take a look at the arguments of the [print](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) function

Comment: `print(*str(N))`

Answer (score 1):

for example, you can transform the int to a string and join with a space. It will consider the string a list, and it will join the numbers with a space:

```
' '.join(str(1000))

#Output '1 0 0 0'`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually iterate over each character in a string with a for loop! So you could get away with something like:

```
my_string = "something goes here"
placeholder_string = ""
for x in my_string:
     placeholder_string+=x
     placeholder_string+=' '
```

You'd end up with an extra space on the end but that's not too hard to manage :-)
I like RegEx so if you wanted to strip any trailing whitespace, you could use:

```
import re
placeholder_string = re.sub(r"\s*$","",placeholder_string)
print(placeholder_string) #'s o m e t h i n g   g o e s   h e r e'
```

And as mentioned in the other answer, if you have an int type object, you can change that to a string using `str(int_variable)`